# Trouble converting html files with single quote in name, to pdf using Powershell and headless chrome

Tags: powershell, google-chrome

Using powershell and headless chrome, I am trying to convert html files to pdf.

However, a lot of my html file names contain a single quote. Example: John's Pizza Shop.html

The html files with a single quote in the name are not getting converted to pdf

How can I convert these types of htmls to pdf? Preferably without removing the quote due to affecting downstream processes.

Below is my code, simply defining my destination pdf path and the source html document.
The pdf will not generate, unless the single quote is dropped from the source html.

I've tried escaping but I may be doing it wrong.
example: $srcPath = 'C:\Users\JohnDoe\HTMLtoPDF\John''s Pizza.html'

As I mentioned above, if possible I'd like to solve this programmatically for free, no tools and without dropping the single quote

```
$chromePath = "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
$destPath = "C:\Users\JohnDoe\HTMLtoPDF\John's Pizza.pdf"
$srcPath = "C:\Users\JohnDoe\HTMLtoPDF\John's Pizza.html"

& $chromePath --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf=$destPath $srcPath
```

Comment: Try doubling the single quotes in the strings to escape them

Comment: Perhaps `$srcPath` must be a `file://` URL? Try `file:///C:/Users/JohnDoe/HTMLtoPDF/John%27s%20&%20Pizza.pdf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For chrome (and edge), you must convert the single quotes to `%27`. For example:

```
$srcPath = "C:\Users\JohnDoe\HTMLtoPDF\John's Pizza.html" -replace "'","%27"
```

It does not require escaping other characters like spaces either (in my testing).

Seems like buggy behavior with the print to pdf function, since chromium can open file paths with single quotes just fine, then manually print them to pdf.